# Reference count increment/decrement in openssl C API

Tags: openssl, api, c

I recently started working on a library that uses openssl's C API, and I am intrigued as to why sometimes the return values have  "reference count incremented". From the decription of X509_get_pubkey:

`X509_get_pubkey() attempts to decode the public key for certificate x. If successful it returns the public key as an EVP_PKEY pointer with its reference count incremented: this means the returned key must be freed up after use.`

..Why exactly does that mean that it needs to be freed ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: This is a pure coding question, i.e. off-topic here and on-topic on Stackoverflow.com.  But in general: many objects in OpenSSL are referenced counted, i.e. there is an XXX_new, XXX_up_ref, XXX_dup, XXX_free ... with XXX being something like EVP_PKEY. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_free.html for more

Comment: It means the library is remembering you are using the key (by means of keeping a count of how many references there are to the key) so that it will keep the memory being used for it. When you are done using the key, you should call `EVP_PKEY_free` to tell the library you are done using the key, after which it can release the reserved memory if there are no other references to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answers. Both were really useful and I think I understand it now. I was not aware of how OPENSSL free functions interacted with this reference count value. I assume it is someting used to generalize clean up routines such that the code remains unchanged even when a user is in charge of freeing.